# Dump full trace logs when crm won't print them

Tags: c#, crm, microsoft-dynamics, trace

I use tracing in my plugin and have a section of my code where I catch a potential WebException:

```
_traceService.Trace("This message is not logged");
try
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        _traceService.Trace("Success");
        _traceService.Trace(jsonTextReader.ToString());
        var ret = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
        sw.Stop();
        _traceService.Trace("MadeRequest {0}", sw.Elapsed);
        return ret;
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()))
    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        _traceService.Trace("Error");
        _traceService.Trace("Error: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

If I hit the exception, I expect my CRM trace logs to have all messages traced before the exception, but instead my trace log only has the web exception. I can't even see the "Error" and "Error: " + e.Message statements. How can I make this easier to debug?

Also, this code is in a different class than my main plugin logic, could that change anything?

Answer (score 1):

This won't write to the trace log unless the exception is unhandled and allowed to propagate. If you can update to CRM 2015 SP1 or later, you could use the solution presented here

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2015/04/28/plug-in-tracing-in-dynamics-crm-2015-update-1

In my worflow actvities I have avoided the tracing altogether and handled every exception and returned the result back to the calling workflow/action to handle. Plugins are a different matter and the solution to your scenario could be to throw the exception.